# Show dynamic bootstrap popup content in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I want to dynamically pass value in bootstrap popup without local variable reference. In below code I have used "localTitle" and it is working fine, but I don't want to initialize all the variables because there are too many. Is there any way I can dynamically replace variables in html by passing in functions?

With google I came across various thread with $scope examples which didn't worked for me in Angular 6.

Below is the code for app.component.html and app.component.ts. And here is the working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vjangular-popup

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  infoModalRef: BsModalRef;
  localTitle = 'hi';
  myList = ["one","two","three"];

constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) { }

  showInfoPopup(template: TemplateRef<any>, userName) {
    this.localTitle = "Title for =>"+userName;
    this.infoModalRef = this.modalService.show(template);
    // this.infoModalRef.componentInstance.title = userName;
  }
  hideInfo() {
    this.infoModalRef.hide();
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let list of myList">
  <a class="text-primary" (click)="showInfoPopup(infoModal, list);">
   Click for popup {{list}}
    </a>
 </div>


<!-- Modal start -->
<ng-template #infoModal>
 <div class="modal-content modified_modal">
  <div class="modal-header">
   <span class="m-auto">Additional Information</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="modal-inner">
            {{localTitle}}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-green btn-border m-auto" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="hideInfo();">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <!-- Modal end -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `RxJS` can help you here. As we know, Angular is already using this under the hood. It's perfectly safe to use `Subject` from RxJS. The `Subject` can broadcast the changes multiple times to multiple listeners and can be subscribed from anywhere in the Angular application.

To achieve this, may be you need to move `infoModel` html code to another new component, then create a `Subject` in your `AppComponent` and subscribe to it in your `infoModel` component, whenever `localTitle`, just send to the subscriber in the `infoModel` component, using `subjectName.next(localTitle)` method, without initializing other variables or Model popup.

For more: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject